# In my service, i want to load the path through another service

Tags: java, angularjs, http, service

I have an angular webapp.

It has one service that will query a simple node api on the same server. 
That api takes the name of an environment variable as parameter and return the path to the java api that matches that environment variable.

```
servicesModule.factory('EnvVarApi', function($http){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/variable_env/';
    return {
        getUrlApi : function(var_env, callbackSuccess) {
            $http.get(url+ var_env).success(callbackSuccess);
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine. It returns an object of the form:
{"cle" : API_KEY, "valeur" : API_PATH}

Now i want to create another service, that will query that java api (I will have 3 of them at the end)..
How would i go about retrieving the path to that API only ONCE? And once it loaded return the correct resource. Atm it's breaking because the resource returned has a null path before the callback.

```
servicesModule.factory('ApiRef', function($resource, EnvVarApi){
    var url = null;
    EnvVarApi.getUrlApi('APIREF_KEY', function(data) {
        if (data) {
            url = data.valeur;
        }
    });

    return $resource(url, {'cle' : '@cle'}, {
        put : {method : 'PUT'}
    });
});
```

The first call is made fine and return the path, however as expected it breaks because i'm return a $resource with a null url at first.
And there is maybe a better way to do that than to inject my first service in my second service.

**EDIT : FIXED** thanks to answer marked bellow.

Here the final code:

```
servicesModule.factory('EnvVarApi', function($http){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/api/variable_env/';
    return {
        getUrlApi : function(var_env) {
            return $http.get(url+ var_env);
        }
    }
});
```

And

```
servicesModule.factory('ApiRef',['$q','$http', 'EnvVarApi',function ($q,$http, EnvVarApi) {

    var defer = $q.defer();
    EnvVarApi.getUrlApi('APIREF_KEY').then(function (resp) {
        defer.resolve($http.get(resp.data.valeur));
    });
    return defer.promise;
}]);
```

Comment: You could create a wrapper of `$resource` to defer http requests until the url is ready. But there may be a better alternative such as request all of the urls in advance before an angular bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $q service, check code below

```
app.factory('call2',['$q','$http',function ($q,$http) {
    var url = 'whatever url';
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get(url).then(function (resp) {
        defer.resolve($http.get(resp.data)); 
        //resp.data contains the returned by $http request URL object
    });
    return defer.promise;
}]);
```

At Controller o Directive side (remember to inject service into controller)

```
call2.then(function (resp) {
    $scope.response = resp.data;
    //resp.data will contain the response of '$http.get(resp.data)'
})
```

you can use $resource instead of $http.get, see below

```
app.factory('call2', ['$q', '$resource', function ($q, $resource) {
   var url = 'whatever url';
   var defer = $q.defer();
   $resource(url).get(function (resp) {
   defer.resolve($resource(resp.url).get().$promise);
  });
  return defer.promise;
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you, i just had to inject my first service (EnvVarApi) into the second as to not hardcode the url. Then remove the callbackSuccess and add a return in the getUrlApi method and it works fine.

Comment: Still wondering however if the best way to do this is inside the service or should i've chained / nested the call inside the controller?

Answer (score 0):

$http.get returns a promise, the simple thing to do is to resolve the promise in your controller... not in a factory. Meaning no .success() in your factory... only in the controller

If you need this in the service... it would be like so:

```
servicesModule.factory('ApiRef', function($resource, EnvVarApi){
    var url = null;

    // this is ASYNC, meaning it will got to the return statement below and wait until the promise is resolved to assign the url
    EnvVarApi.getUrlApi('APIREF_KEY', function(data) {
        if (data) {
            url = data.valeur;
            $resource(url, {'cle' : '@cle'}, { // url defined here, gets put correctly
                put : {method : 'PUT'}
            });
        }
    });

    return $resource(url, {'cle' : '@cle'}, {
        put : {method : 'PUT'}
    });
});
```

Comment: Aye i guess i should put it in my controller that way i only call my service when the url is loaded. However i still want to query the path only once when the application load for the first time. NOt everytime i query, nor everytime i change page.